# Is there a way to use java LocalDateTime.now() in jpa @query?

Tags: jpa, java-8, spring-data, localdatetime

I'm using Spring data jpa and i have an update function

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Notification n SET n.read=true WHERE n.creationDate < ?1")
void update(LocalDateTime now);
```

And i want something like this

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Notification n SET n.read=true WHERE n.creationDate < LocalDateTime.now()")
void update(LocalDateTime now);
```

Is it possible with java 8 LocaleDateTime ? How can i achieve this ?

Comment: You can always use the auditing feature. `@LastModifiedDate`. You do not need to write the query!

Comment: Yes. It answers my question. Thank you !